Need help with a vertical form in a pane above a table

I'm struggling to add a form that needs to sit in a pane above a table. The form fields needs to be vertically arranged. It currently feels...off. I've tried centring it and stretching the card to 100% width, but neither help it make look less awkward. Does anyone have any suggestion on what to do with that extra space? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Can you tell what the relationship is between the form and the table? Is that form a filter for the table data perhaps? Maybe there’s a different problem than just the spacing.

The table below is inside a white frame and the form is an image that floats on the screen.
I would go for the "window effect", enclosing the image (the form) in a slightly darker frame, for example using the grey of the bottom line of the table header.

